# BigQuery, how to return one value if there is duplicate based on a condition

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this table

REGIONID    STRING
SETTLEMENTDATE  TIMESTAMP
INTERVENTION    STRING
RRP NUMERIC

most of the time, intervention is 0, but in same cases, it has two records (0,1) then RRP has to be based on the value 1, how to do that in SQL ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT REGIONID, SETTLEMENTDATE, 
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(INTERVENTION, RRP) ORDER BY INTERVENTION DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].* 
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY REGIONID, SETTLEMENTDATE
```

Answer (score 1):

The following can be used to achieve the desired result:

```
SELECT *, EXCEPT(RN) FROM ( 
  SELECT RRP, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition BY REGIONID, SETTLEMENTDATE ORDER BY INTERVENTION DESC) AS RN
)
WHERE RN=1
```